# Isometry group G is a compact?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, arzela-ascoli

Hello everyone I found the following statement in my lecture but I'm not sure why it's true.

> Let $(X,d) $ a metric space (compact). Hence we can say that the isometry group G is a compact in $(C(X,X),d_\infty)$ i.e $G$ is a family of closed and equicontinuous applications.

I thought that using Arzelà-Ascoli theorem would help but it leads nowhere. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by ``Arzelà-Ascoli theorem leads nowhere''? You should be able to apply it straightforwardly.

Comment: I couldn't find any $\left|f_n(x)-f_n(y)\right| < \varepsilon$

Comment: Not sure how you intend to subtract points of $X$.... perhaps you mean $d(f_n(x),f_n(y)) < \epsilon$? If so, you should make use of the isometry property $d(f_n(x),f_n(y))=d(x,y)$.

Comment: That's the thing I missed ... sorry I got it know thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $f_n$ be a sequence of isometries. Consider $h_n(x)=d(x,f_n(x))$
show that the family $h_n$ is absolutely bounded and equicontinuous.

Ascoli implies the existence of a subsequence $h_p$ which converges towards $h$; $h_p(x)=d(x,f_p(x))$ is a Cauchy sequence implies that $(f_p(x))$ is Cauchy and $f_p(x)$ converges towards $f(x)$. Show that $f$ is an isometry.